# Enter datas in excel using python

Tags: python-2.7

I need to enter data's in a particular column in excel using python.

I am new to python and i am eager to involve with this scripting.

I expect the script that ask for a dialog to enter the data and the given data should import in the excel in the particular column.Can anyone help me?

Comment: check openpyxl lib

Comment: can you please look at openpyxl? that's a good example; if you google you find lib and good documentation with examples

Comment: let me google that for you ... if exactly your question is put in google you get (as the first result)directly lib page with all the info including support versions... you definitely have to learn how to use google.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shall use `openpyxl` to manipulate excel.

Example:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws.title = "Sheet Name"
ws['B2'] = "Test Data 1"
# or
d = ws.cell(row=1, column=2, value="Test Data 2")
wb.save('D:\\Prabhakar\\Sample\\balances.xlsx')
```

Ref: [Openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/)